# Can static method access non-static instance variable?

Tags: java, variables, static

So my understanding was that you can't use static method to access non-static variables, but I came across following code.

```
class Laptop {
  String memory = "1GB";
}
class Workshop {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Laptop life = new Laptop();
    repair(life);
    System.out.println(life.memory);
    }
  public static void repair(Laptop laptop) {
    laptop.memory = "2GB";
  }
}
```

Which compiles without errors.

So isn't

```
public static void repair(Laptop laptop) {
laptop.memory = "2GB";
}
```

accessing String memory defined in class Laptop, which is non-static instance variable?

Since the code compiles without any error, I'm assuming I'm not understanding something here. Can someone please tell me what I'm not understanding?

Comment: If you had a non static field in Workshop, you could not access that from the static context. But it's perfectly fine to access the non-static field of the non-static object you created **inside** the static context.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A static method can access non-static methods and fields of any instance it knows of. However, it cannot access anything non-static if it doesn't know which instance to operate on.

I think you're mistaking by examples like this that don't work:

```
class Test {
  int x;

  public static doSthStatically() {
    x = 0; //doesn't work!
  }
}
```

Here the static method doesn't know which instance of `Test` it should access. In contrast, if it were a non-static method it would know that `x` refers to `this.x` (the `this` is implicit here) but `this` doesn't exist in a static context.

If, however, you provide access to an instance even a static method can access `x`.

Example:

```
class Test {
  int x;
  static Test globalInstance = new Test();

  public static doSthStatically( Test paramInstance ) {
    paramInstance.x = 0; //a specific instance to Test is passed as a parameter
    globalInstance.x = 0; //globalInstance is a static reference to a specific instance of Test

    Test localInstance = new Test();
    localInstance.x = 0; //a specific local instance is used
  }
}
```

Comment: One important thing to note is globalInstance is static.
doSthStatically method will not be able to access globalInstance.x if it wasn't static.

Answer (score 0):

You can access only with `object reference`.

Instance variables defined at class level, have to be qualified with object name if you are using in a static context. **But it does not not mean that you cannot access at all.**

Answer (score 0):

Static methods cannot modify their value. 
You can get their current value by accessing them with the reference of current class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a non-static method can access a static variable or call a static method in Java. There is no problem with that because of static members

i.e. both static variable and static methods belongs to a class and can be called from anywhere, depending upon their access modifier.

For example, if a static variable is private then it can only be accessed from the class itself, but you can access a public static variable from anywhere.

Similarly, a private static method can be called from a non-static method of the same class but a public static method e.g. `main()` can be called from anywhere

Answer (score -2):

try this code

```
public static void repair() {

    Laptop laptop =new Laptop();

    laptop.memory="2GB";

  }
```